# How to use breakpoints in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I am using the Eclipse IDE. I don't know how effectively put *breakpoints* in Eclipse and go forward and backward into it. Can anyone help me?

Can anyone suggest a site suitable for me?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To put breakpoints in your code, **double click in the left margin on the line you want execution to stop on**. You may alternatively put your cursor in this line and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

To control execution use the ***Step Into***, ***Step Over*** and ***Step Return*** buttons. They have the shortcuts <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd> respectively.

To allow execution to continue normally or until it hits the next breakpoint, hit the Resume button or <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Comment: Can't believe there is no default keyboard shortcut for putting a breakpoint on the current line. Or did u not mention it?

Comment: @dotNet Yes there is one: Shift+Ctrl+B (I added it to the answer)

Comment: At first, when double click in the left margin or Ctrl+Shift+B did not work to add a break-point, we restarted the Eclipse and then everything worked well.

Comment: a politically correct answer is not as popular as a helpful one by the looks of it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a video about [Debugging with eclipse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drk_ldaRMaY).

For more details [read this page](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html).

Instead of ***Debugging as Java program***, use ***Debug as Android Application***

May help new comers.

Answer (score 2):

Put breakpoints - double click on the margin. 
Run > Debug > Yes (if dialog appears), then use commands from Run menu or shortcuts - F5, F6, F7, F8.

Answer (score -1):

Googling gives many sites... [Debugging with the Eclipse platform](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/) for one.

Answer (score -1):

Breakpoints are just used to check the execution of your code, wherever you will put breakpoints the execution will stop there, so you can just check that your project execution is going forward or not. To get more details follow link:-

http://javapapers.com/core-java/top-10-java-debugging-tips-with-eclipse/

Comment: Irrelevant answer.