# What is the little tick on top of the blue breakpoint marker in Eclipse means?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When you toggle a breakpoint in Eclipse, on the left you get a blue marker.
Sometimes the blue marker is accompanied with a tick, what does that mean?
Thank you

Edit:
It seems non of you know exactly what I am talking about, here goes the pic of it...
[image: breakpoint with/without tick]
and in the breakpoint panel [image: breakpoint panel]

Comment: If you hover the mouse on the marker, you should see a yellow box expanding it. What does it say?

Comment: These are BreakPoints,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733835/how-use-break-points-in-eclipse

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The tick is only shown when you have an active debug session at that line. It means your breakpoint is active and attached to the bytecode running in debug mode. Debugger cannot (and will never) stop at breakpoints without that "tick".

If you don't have this "tick" at some lines then your have differences between the bytecode and the source code you debug. This can happen when debugged bytecode has not been produced by the attached source code or bytecode has been compiled without debugging information like line numbers etc.

Comment: Almost a good answer. Why do I get a tick only on some lines but not the others (like in the picture)?

Comment: It can be that you have a difference between bytecode and source code. If debugger finds lines in source code corresponding to actual bytecode, then these lines will have a "tick" on them. Other lines can have a breakpoint, but this is a "dead" breakpoint, because actual code will never run through them. Sometimes compiler optimizes bytecode and you can have similar picture too. Shortly speaking, if there is no "tick", debugger will never run through these lines, because they do not match running bytecode.

Comment: Nice for pointing out a mismatch on bytecode and source code. I guess thats the case: my code is newer than the running SNAPSHOT that I am not aware of.

Comment: @sergejshafarenka How can I check if there are any differences between the bytecode and the source code on which I have placed my breakpoint?