# How to step through running Android app's code in Eclipse/ADT?

Tags: android-debug

Just started using latest Eclipse + ADT to develop Android apps.
Wrote the MyFirstApp from  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html
Testing it on a virtual 4.2 machine.
This simple app involves entering text in a window, clicking a button to send the text to a separate Activity which is supposed to redisplay the text.
The redisplay doesn't happen.
So I want to find out what is happening after I press the button.

I ran the app as best I could in debug mode : right-click on the project -> Debug as -> Android application.
The debug window shows messages until the app loads in the virtual device and then no more... i.e. no debug output for the actual running app.
So how do I make it actually step through the app's code ?
thanks
Rod (noob)

Answer (score 1):

D'uh - the answer is here : [How to use breakpoints in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733835/how-use-break-points-in-eclipse) :

"To put break points in your code, double click in the left margin on the line you want execution to stop on.
To control execution use the Step Into, Step Over and Step Return buttons. They have the shortcuts F5, F6 and F7 respectively.
To allow execution to continue normally or until it hits the next breakpoint, hit the Resume button or F8."

I hadn't realised that it needs at least one breakpoint to give me an entry into the running code.
Rod