# Eclipse java Debug - debug my own classes

Tags: java

Could I filter my debug into eclipse? For exemple: I've a library that connect to my database but a don't need debug these components. How can I filter or debug my own classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain simple: then put a **break point** into *your* class. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733835/how-to-use-breakpoints-in-eclipse) for example.

And understand that *you* can tell the debugger to jump **into** a method - or to **not** do that.

Meaning: you can easily make sure to "not enter" code you don't want to "step by step" into using the debugger.

But there is no mechanism to "exclude" certain classes from the debugger - because the debugger of course has to **run** all code that is required to be run.