# Looking for something void

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I'm looking for a command/line that does literally nothing, is as short and simple as possible, but allows me to place a breakpoint on it. (in Eclipse)

What I've tried:

```
System.out.println(""); //Too long, also it prints an empty line
boolean b = false; //Also too long + could cause interferences
; // Doesn't let me place a breakpoint on it in Eclipse
if (true); //Doesn't trigger
```

I need this for conditional breakpoints. (certain indexes in a for-loop for example)

---

I am aware of conditional breakpoints in Eclipse, but I'm still looking for that void line. (partially because of plain interest, and partially because I don't like clicking things and relying purely on the IDE)

Comment: why would you want this? adding code just so you can put a breakpoint?

Comment: Conditional breakpoints. Where I have something like `if (i == arr.length -1) void();`

Comment: Doesn't eclipse support setting a condition on a breakpoint?

Comment: If no debugging on expressions: then it has to be (generated!) code, hence `if (i == 13) {` _[BreakPointHere]_ `i = i^0; }`. A senseless no-op I do not know, as I am a serious developer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the assert-Statement:

```
assert true;
```

But you have to activate asserts. In Eclipse see [Eclipse: enable assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509082/eclipse-enable-assertions)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding code simply for setting breakpoints, you can set a java expression as a breakpoint condition in eclise:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F

(other IDEs support this as well, but the question was about Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Use empty curly brackets **{}** , that'll probably do, or
Semi-colon **;** actually will do as well.

Comment: I've already stated in the question, that Eclipse doesn't allow me to set a breakpoint on `;` - same goes for curly brackets unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[This Eclipse page](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php) shows that by right-clicking or double clicking the left margin of the Eclipse code editor, you can toggle breakpoints.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733835/how-to-use-breakpoints-in-eclipse) also has some good info on setting breakpoints.

**Edit:**

If you don't want to toggle breakpoints through the Eclipse interface, you could just write your own method of type void and call that. For example:

```
public void wait() {} // Empty method
```

And then you can just call the method wherever you want to set a breakpoint.